# The polynomial is dense in $L^2$ with non-lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Assume the function $u\to \mathbb E[e^{iuX}]$ is analytic in a nbhd of $0$ where $X$: $\Omega\to \mathbb R$ is a random variable.

Now I want to conclude that the space of polynomial, denoted by $\mathbb T$, is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R,\,\mathbb P\circ X^{-1})$ with $L^2$ norm, where $\mathbb P$: $\Omega\to [0,1]$ is a probability measure.

I think as long as $\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}$ forms a Radon measure then I am done. But I am not sure about this since $X$ maybe pretty bad. I think I should use the property that $u\to \mathbb E[e^{iuX}]$ is analytic but I can't see how...

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: Any (locally) finite measure on $\Bbb{R}$ is Radon, since $\Bbb{R}$ is locally compact and second countable. You will have to use the condition of analyticity somewhere, since in general the polynomials do not even have to be in the $L^2$ space you are considering.

Comment: Maybe this could give you a starting point: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949787/show-that-polynomials-are-complete-on-the-real-line

Comment: @PhoemueX Wow it's a long proof! I will read it carefully tonight. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @PhoemueX hmm... Sir, could you provide more ideas? I still can not extract any useful information form function $mathbb E[e^{iuX}]$ being analytic...

Comment: @PhoemueX I proved it! It is not that hard, just have sth to do with Radon measure and no need to use analytic...

Comment: I dont really think that is possible. The statement is not true for general Radon probability measures. I will try to adapt my other proof tomorrow.

Comment: @PhoemueX hmm... then I may did sth wrong... I will try to write up my proof in my post...